# Elasticsearch Query String vs Boolean Filtered Query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to Elastic search. I found that these two queries are the same:
using query_string:

```
{"query": {"query_string":{"query": "obama love", "fields": ["title"]}}}
```

using boolean query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "terms": {
              "title": ["obama", "love"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What is the different between these two and which should I use?

Comment: Performance wise, the second query uses filters which uses the OS cache and thus it is considered as resources greedy where the first uses just the full-text search feature and should give better performance. I suggest that you use the explain API so you get a better grip over the difference between these kind of queries

Comment: @eliasah in the above  query no filters are used since there is only query section of the filtered query,The difference i see is In query string the query term is analyzed but not so when using terms.But not sure if that is what the OP's question is about